# Angular pushing object in model

Tags: html, angularjs

I have a list of objects that I'm iterating over and the models I'm defining are accessing a key that doesn't exist. I was wondering if its possible to implicitly push an object when defining a model so that the key I access isn't undefined..

Basic example:

```
<div ng-repeat="person in persons">
  <input type='text' ng-model='person.data.firstname' />
  <input type='text' ng-model='person.data.lastname' />
</div>
```

Here the `data` object of `person` is undefined so I get an error. If I wrap the inputs above in a form with name `person.data` then the `data` object isn't undefined however I was wondering why the models I specified aren't implicitly pushing the `data` object to `person` if it doesn't exist like form is doing?

Answer (score 0):

From what I can understand of your question, in your scope you can have a "master" object that you use to initialize a new object.

```
$scope.persons = [];

// Master Object
var masterPerson = {
    data: {
        firstname: "",
        lastname: ""
    }
};

// When doing the ng-click event. This will allow you to use some default data
$scope.addNewPerson = function(newPerson) {
    newPerson = angular.merge(angular.copy(masterPerson), newPerson);
    $scope.persons.push(newPerson);
};
```